# F1 help in Qt Creator (Opensource)?

Tags: 12.04, qt-creator

I have installed Qt Creator 2.7.2 'Based on Qt 5.1.0 (32 bit)'. Is it possible to set it for getting direct help in the Edit mode, maybe by pressing F1 key, as I am used to from the Microsoft Visual Studio? Now, I can get help by copying a chosen term to the Help mode index, clicking at it and then switch back to the Edit mode. I wish to let the found help in another window simultaneously with the edited C++ source code, maybe in the other part of the window, if it is split.

Answer (score 1):

In the 'Qt Creator' menu Tools...Options...Help...Startup...'On context help:' set 'Always Show Side-by-Side'.